# How to use Session - Length Trigger?

Tags: smarttarget

SmartTarget includes a `Session - Length Trigger` by [default](http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL_SmartTarget_2014_SP1-v1/GUID-F167829F-C22A-4208-A8B1-7486325B0FF2), which triggers a "Promotion based on the duration of the user session."

I have two questions:

1. Is this number in **seconds**?
2. Is this only available when the visitor visits a given page "on the first hit?"

*In other words, is the Length Trigger available in near real-time, possibly from JavaScript?*

The way I understand the triggers (claims) is that they're known when the visitor hits the page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is measured in **minutes** and it is updated on every request. It is a claim added by the Session Cartridge and as such is only available in the Ambient Data Framework. If you need it, you could expose it to JavaScript yourself by outputting it in the response.

Comment: Ok, so we could put the value itself in the response or use it to trigger some other content (promotion) on the page. From there, we have plenty of client-side things we can do with session length. :-)

Comment: Sure. It is set in onRequestStart so the updated value is available when the page loads. From there you can do with it as you want. And of course it's one of the default triggers so you can easily set up a Promotion based on it.